# Eclipse Gradle export of Android project does nothing

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

I'm trying to export my Android project from Eclipse (ADT 22.2.1) using the Gradle plugin.

I select my project in the initial Gradle dialog, click next

[image]

My project appears along with Android dependencies.

[image]

When I click on Finish, I can barely see a message "Creating Gradle Build files" BUT I never get a confirmation of Success. And build.gradle or settings.gradle ARE NOT in my projects root directory.

I can select each of the dependency libraries and they complete successfully

Any suggestions?

jb

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, my solution was install the lastest Eclipse from [their page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads), (i was using Juno, now with Kepler didn't have that problem), and Android ADT plugin [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html). Seems that they have breaked compatibility with older eclipse version in newer ADTs

An ankward one, but...at least it works

You can try it "the hard way", creating required files (build.gradle, gradle wrapper et al) by hand, but you will got a lot of mistakes, didn't worth the time spent.

EDIT : Extracted from [Android Tools Tech Docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects) : *Open the project in Eclipse, and from there, export the project. NOTE: Make sure you are using the latest possible version of Eclipse since we have fixed issues related to export recently.*